# Why PHP both logical operator condition is not working?

Tags: php

I have following code in PHP:

```
<?php 
if( Session::exists('logged_tutor') === false OR 
    Session::exists('logged_student') === false ) { 
    // show login and registration button
} else {
    // show profile and logout link
}

?>
```

Here, Either `logged_tutor` or `logged_student` is `false`. So it's should show me **profile and logout** link but it's always showing the **login and registration** button.

Is there anything I am missing?

Updated:

```
var_dump( Session::exists('logged_tutor') == false OR  Session::exists('logged_student') == false );
```

It returns true.

But I want if either logged_tutor or logged_student is true then **show me profile and logout link.**

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump(Session::exists('logged_tutor'), Session::exists('logged_student'));` and tell us the result?

Comment: Do what @VitalijKornijenko suggested and post the output **in the question and not in the comments**.

Comment: @AbraCadaver how can I make the condition?

Comment: You edited, it works correctly. `IF either one is false` show _show login and registration button_ `IF none are false` show _show profile and logout link_

Comment: I have updated my question again @AbraCadaver Please check that.

Comment: I am taking bets that the OR should be an AND

Comment: Your logic is incorrect. if (logged_tutor) is not false the logged_student will be false and it will show the login / registration button. Same thing when logged_student is not false.

Comment: Wrong update, see how @VitalijKornijenko did

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am confused what will be the correct logic here :(

Comment: Try `var_dump(Session::get('logged_tutor')); var_dump(Session::get('logged_student'));` The key is to find out what is in those variables, if they do exist.

Comment: You're after AND, not OR.

Comment: The logic is correct. logged_tutor and logged_studends are both true according to the logic

Comment: @manix it's return false `var_dump(Session::exists('logged_tutor'), Session::exists('logged_student'));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case, your code should be this. You expect for both of them to be false so AND operator is the solution.

```
<?php 
if( Session::exists('logged_tutor') === false AND 
    Session::exists('logged_student') === false ) { 
    // show login and registration button
} else {
    // show profile and logout link
}

?>
```

Alternatively, if you want either the student or tutor session to exist to show profile, then do the following:

```
<?php 
if( Session::exists('logged_tutor') === true OR
    Session::exists('logged_student') === true) { 
    // show profile and logout link
} else {
    // show login and registration button
}

?>
```

In both cases you will achieve the exact same result, it all depends on you which one to use.

Comment: I think that it could fix the problem.. but what happen if the OP is using different profiles in the app? I think that OP should clear the context here

Comment: I am testing it but I want either tutor or student session is exist then show the profile and logout button.

Comment: I think I may have won [my bet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738382/why-php-both-logical-operator-condition-is-not-working#comment86491373_49738382), pity nobody took my bet

Comment: OH, I understand now. :(

Comment: Thanks a lot Vitalij :)

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed no problem. To learn more about such things, google for truth table logic. It will all make sense eventually.